# doit - is there a command line option to force rerun a specific task

Tags: doit

I'm using doit to automiate some data analysis pipeline. During development/debug time, it is often necessary to rerun a task even its file dependencies haven't changed. I was wondering whether there is a command line option to achieve this. I've searched the document but could not find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just run with the parameter `-a`, `--always-execute`.

It is mentioned in a note in the [tutorial](https://pydoit.org/tutorial_1.html#forget).

Comment: Thanks @schettino72. 

Just for other's benefit, the full command is like `doit --single -a <task_name>`